# Speed up animations Android emulator

Tags: android, animation, android-emulator

Does anyone know of a way to programmatically speed up all animations on your Android emulator? Either via an option when starting the emulator via adb, or a method you can call once your app starts. I know about the developer option which speeds up animations, but when running automation tests, I need a way to speed up animations without manual intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found at least a partial solution. You can have a resource folders for each build flavor your support. As long as all your animations durations are set via a resource file (i.e. numbers.xml) then you can copy that file into src/*buildFlavorHere*/res/values and set all the values to zero.

However, if you're trying to speed up animations that run during tests run from androidTest (we run screenshot based automation there), this method won't work. If anyone has a good idea what to do there, please share.